# Quickblox chat message didn't sent after reconnect

Tags: ios, quickblox

I have problem with sending messages after reconnecting with the quickblox server. The user is automatically logout in the middle of chatting with the others and after reconnect with the server again, the chat messages is not sending. But the log shown it was sent , not showing the receive log. The reconnect code works fine but cannot chat anymore.

when it was working as fine,

```
    2013-10-12 10:48:37.033 football365[1000:8517] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendMessage:] ->              Message: <message to="4099_000000001000000003@muc.chat.quickblox.com" id="7" type="groupchat"><body>hello</body></message>
    2013-10-12 10:48:37.463 football365[1000:8517] -[QBChat xmppRoom:didReceiveMessage:fromNick:] -> message: <message xmlns="jabber:client" type="groupchat" to="578338-4099@chat.quickblox.com/tigase-11258" from="4099_000000001000000003@muc.chat.quickblox.com/578338"><body>hello</body></message> fromNick: 578338
```

when message only sent, the received log is not shown.

```
    2013-10-12 10:48:37.033 football365[1000:8517] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendMessage:] ->              Message: <message to="4099_000000001000000003@muc.chat.quickblox.com" id="7" type="groupchat"><body>hello</body></message>
```

the login code in DataManager.m.

```
    - (void)chatLogin{
        QBASessionCreationRequest *extendedAuthRequest = [QBASessionCreationRequest request];
        extendedAuthRequest.userLogin = @"userid";
        extendedAuthRequest.userPassword = @"password";
        [QBAuth createSessionWithExtendedRequest:extendedAuthRequest delegate:self];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    }

    - (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{
        if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:QBAAuthSessionCreationResult.class]){
            QBAAuthSessionCreationResult *res = (QBAAuthSessionCreationResult *)result; 
            currentUser = [QBUUser user];
            currentUser.ID = res.session.userID;
            currentUser.password = @"password";
            [[DataManager shared] setCurrentUser: currentUser];
            [QBChat instance].delegate = self;
            [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:currentUser];
        }
    }
```

reconnect code in chatViewController.m,

```
    -(void)chatDidFailWithError:(int)code
    {
        [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:currentUser];
    }
```

Comment: Please provide code how you do reconnect

Comment: [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:currentUser]; login again after chatDidFailWithError to reconnect the chat. Is it wrong?

Comment: it's correct, still isn't working?

Comment: reconnect code is working fine. But after joining a chat room and if  chatDidFailWithError occured, reconnect again and sending message is not working as shown as above logs. xmppStream:didSendMessage is shown but not showing messages in the room and it is not receiving message as well.

Comment: please provide full code how you do a reconnect

Comment: Can you update your question :)
quite hard to read in comments

Comment: OK, Sorry about that.